# Re-trying levels

Tags: invisible-inc

Both in-game text and forums suggest that when you restart level/day the level is re-generated. My experience was that when you restart day you get the same levels. I once started a day over after seeing two levels and both remained exactly the same as I saw them first time.

Did I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?